# Why does calling `write` in aioinflux with an iterable of a user-defined dataclass seem to only insert the last item?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, influxdb, aioinflux

I've been trying to insert the data contained in a list, inside a running influxdb server.
The list contains items of the following type **CoordInfluxData**:

```
from aioinflux.serialization.usertype import FLOAT, INT, TIMEINT, lineprotocol
from dataclasses import dataclass

@lineprotocol(
    schema=dict(lon=INT, lat=INT, time=TIMEINT, humidity=FLOAT, wind_speed=FLOAT)
)
@dataclass
class CoordInfluxData(dict):
    lon: int
    lat: int
    time: int
    humidity: float
    wind_speed: float
```

I'm using influxdb1.8 and I can't understand why inserting an iterable of such a user-defined dataclass, not only seems to only insert the last item of the iterable in the db, but even if I explicitly call `write` and provide a `measurement` argument, the measurement does not get created in the db. The only measurement that gets created has the same name as the custom dataclass I attempt to write.

Here's a sample script

```
import asyncio
from dataclasses import dataclass

from aioinflux import InfluxDBClient
from aioinflux.serialization.usertype import FLOAT, INT, TIMEINT, lineprotocol


@lineprotocol(
    schema=dict(lon=INT, lat=INT, time=TIMEINT, humidity=FLOAT, wind_speed=FLOAT)
)
@dataclass
class CoordInfluxData(dict):
    lon: int
    lat: int
    time: int
    humidity: float
    wind_speed: float


async def main():
    db_name = "coord_data"
    data = [
        CoordInfluxData(
            lon=164, lat=-15, time=1649938757, humidity=75, wind_speed=5.36
        ),
        CoordInfluxData(lon=33, lat=-18, time=1649938757, humidity=73, wind_speed=0.99),
        CoordInfluxData(
            lon=139, lat=18, time=1649938757, humidity=86, wind_speed=15.13
        ),
    ]

    client = InfluxDBClient(db=db_name)
    await client.create_database(db_name)

    await client.write(data, "weather_data")

    await client.close()


# Call main
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exhaustively studying the reported issue and by carefully looking at the provided data I believe that the problem is that `InfluxDB` identifies the provided points as duplicates. As the [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-duplicate-points) say:

> A point is uniquely identified by the measurement name, tag set, and
> timestamp. If you submit a new point with the same measurement, tag
> set, and timestamp as an existing point, the field set becomes the
> union of the old field set and the new field set, where any ties go to
> the new field set